# How can we export pdf using filemaker pro?

Tags: pdf-generation, export, filemaker

How can we export pdf using filemaker pro?

I want to export pdf in filemaker pro.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu File -> Save/Send Records As -> PDF. There's also a similar script step to use in scripts. It won't work in runtime applications, only in FileMaker itself.